# Заменить текст в xml на заданный

Tags: c#, xml

Есть файл `xml` который имеет вид :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<test title="This Xml will be updated">
    <line1>Xml has been renamed to New Xml</line1>
    <line1>Test has been renamed to Xml</line1>
    <line1>Xml has been renamed to Xml</line1>
    <line1>XmlXml has been renamed to New Xml</line1>
    <line1>Xml has been renamed to Xml</line1>
</test>
```

Нужно заменить добавить до всех слов `Xml`, слово `New`

Делаю так:

```
string prefix = "New";
string word = "Xml";
string regexPattern = $@"(?<!\b{prefix}\s+){word}\b";
string replacement = $"{prefix} $&";
XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Load(xmlFile.FullName);

foreach (var node in xdoc.Descendants())
{
    node.Value = Regex.Replace(node.Value, regexPattern, replacement);

    foreach (var attribute in node.Attributes())
    {
        attribute.Value = Regex.Replace(attribute.Value, regexPattern, replacement);
    }
}

return xdoc;
```

Замена происходит, но, почему то удаляются ноды `<line1></line1>` и `xml` становится в виде:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<test title="This New Xml will be updated">New Xml has been renamed to New XmlTest has been renamed to XmlNew Xml has been renamed to XmlXmlNew Xml has been renamed to New XmlNew Xml has been renamed to New Xml</test>
```

Что я делаю не так? В чем моя ошибка?

Comment: Под отладчиком посмотрите что вы перебираете. Что содержит `node.Value` изначально и на что вы его заменяете

Comment: под отладчиком value содержит текст который между <line1></line1>. Но после замены, почему то пропадают <line1></line1>, хотя в node.Value их нет

Comment: Ок, посчитайте сколько итераций делает ваш `foreach`, а сколько вы ожидаете

Comment: хм. одну итерацию на нодах и одну на атрибутах. Но я не совсем понимаю как это исправить

Comment: Добавил еще один вариант

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`xdoc.Descendants()` возвращает первым элементом корень всего документа, т.е. тег `test` со всем его содержимым.

[Свойство `XElement.Value`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.xml.linq.xelement.value(v=vs.110).aspx):

> Возвращает или задает сцепленное текстовое содержимое этого элемента.

Поэтому вы первой же итерацией просто уничтожаете все вложенные теги. Всё, дальше итераций не будет.

Починить можно так:

```
foreach (var node in xdoc.Root.Descendants())
```

или так:

```
foreach (var node in xdoc.Descendants("line1"))
```

Цикл по атрибутам надо будет вынести отдельно.

Еще один вариант (без правки заголовка цикла) — пропускать элементы, имеющие дочерние элементы:

```
if (!node.HasElements)
    node.Value = Regex.Replace(node.Value, regexPattern, replacement);
```

Тогда цикл по атрибутам можно оставить внутри.

<sub>(правильность самой регулярки не проверял)</sub>